# How to sync two repositories with one project

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, repository

I set up visual svn by importing an existing repository, l:\svnRepository (up to revision 96), to d:\Repositories as d:\Repositories\svnRepository.  Unfortunately, I continued to make commitments to the original repository on drive l, up to revision 103.

How do I copy revisions 97 to 103 from l:\svnRepository to d:\Repositories\svnRepository?

Also, how do I back up l: before starting?

Both repositories are on one Windows machine with cygwin installed.  Original repository was created either with tortoise svn or with eclipse (a few years back).

Comment: I tried

svnadmin dump l:/svnRepository -r97:103 > dump.txt
and that appears to have dumped revision 97 to 103

then tried svnadmin load d:/Repositories/svnRepository < dump.txt

get the error E000013: Can't open file d/Repositories/svnRepositroy/db/txn-current-lock  Permission denied

Comment: I don't know how to get the line feeds in the "comment"

Comment: I tried chown and chmod -R 664 and now I get the error E160020, file already exists.  I did "fgrep -n -a -C 1 "Revision number:" file" but not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your comments should be edits/additions to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Command to dump the modified repository

   `svnadmin dump originalPath -r98:103 --incremental > dumpfile`
2. Command to change the owner of files in the new repository

   `chown -R user path/*`
3. Command to change read / write permission

   `chmod -R 664 path/*`
4. Command to load the modifications into the new repository

   `svnadmin load path < dumpfile`

The above steps allow the two repositories to be put in sync.

Comment: This should be an edit to your original post unless it actually resolved the problem (which is not clear if it did).

Comment: The commands listed extracted the revisions from one repository and imported the revisions into the second repository to bring the two repositories into sync.  These steps solved the problem.